# Currency Formatting In Sencha

Tags: sencha-touch

I just started working on Sencha couple of hours ago. What I want is to format currency values on my app.

For example, wherever something appears like 20000 I want it to look like 20,000

I tried looking up on internet and came to know about *Ext.util.Format.number*

So I tried to use it like `Ext.util.Format.number(total_value, “0,000.00”);` wherever I was using `${total_value}`. But that didn't work.

Do I have to include any external files or am I missing anything?

Comment: Ext.util.Format.number() is not ported over to Touch from ExtJS. But We need a good solution, both for normal number/currency formatting and in templates: e.g: {value:number("0.00")}. Starting a bounty..

Comment: Btw, workaround for the decimals in templates: {[values.MyTemplateValue.toFixed(2)]}

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used in my project after realising Ext.util.Format.number() is not part of Sencha Touch, a small JS function which can be used anywhere in my app:

```
/**
 * Given a number this will format it to have comma separated readable number(Rounded off)
 * with currency symbol(Rs.) prefix
 * @example
 * Helper.formatCurrency(123456.78) = "Rs. 123,456"
 * 
 * @param {Number} num
 * @return {Number}
 */
formatCurrency : function(num) {
    num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
    if (isNaN(num))
        num = "0";
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
    num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
        num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + ','
                + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
    return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + 'Rs. ' + num /*+ '.' + cents*/);
},
```

Feel free to copy, change and improvise

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Ext.util.Format.currency(“0,000.00”);`

Comment: Ext.util.Format.number() is not part of Sencha Touch, only part of ExtJS :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  currencyConvertion : function (value){                                               
   return Number(value).toFixed(0).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
              return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
                                  });
                              }
```